# How to unit test ValueProviderFactories in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

We wanted to upgrade our projects from ASP.NET MVC 2 to 3. Most of our tests succeeded, but there are some that fail on `ValueProviderFactories.Factories.GetValueProvider(context)`.

Here is a simple test class that ilustrates the problem.

```
[TestFixture]
public class FailingTest
{
  [Test]
  public void Test()
  {
    var type = typeof(string);
    // any controller
    AuthenticationController c = new AuthenticationController();
    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var context = c.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData(), c);

    IModelBinder converter = ModelBinders.Binders.GetBinder(type);
    var bc = new ModelBindingContext
    {
      ModelName = "testparam",
      ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, type),
      ValueProvider = ValueProviderFactories.Factories.GetValueProvider(context)
    };
    Console.WriteLine(converter.BindModel(context, bc));
  }
}
```

Exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is thrown when `ValueProviderFactories.Factories.GetValueProvider(context)` is called. The stacktrace looks like this:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll!Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.CollectionReplacer.GetUnvalidatedCollections(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x23 bytes   
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll!Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.GetUnvalidatedCollections(System.Web.HttpContext context, out System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection form, out System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection queryString, out System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers, out System.Web.HttpCookieCollection cookies) + 0xbe bytes    
System.Web.WebPages.dll!System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated(System.Web.HttpRequest request) + 0x73 bytes  
System.Web.WebPages.dll!System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated(System.Web.HttpRequestBase request) + 0x25 bytes  
System.Web.Mvc.DLL!System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory..ctor.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext cc) + 0x5a bytes   
System.Web.Mvc.DLL!System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext) + 0xa0 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.DLL!System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider.AnonymousMethod__7(System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactory factory) + 0x4a bytes  
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactory,<>f__AnonymousType2<System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactory,System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider>>.MoveNext() + 0x24d bytes   
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType2<System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactory,System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider>,System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider>.MoveNext() + 0x2ba bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider> collection) + 0x1d8 bytes    
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider> source) + 0xb5 bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.DLL!System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext) + 0x24d bytes 
test.DLL!FailingTest.Test() Line 31 + 0xf9 bytes    C#
```

I wanted to know the reason why it throws the exception and saw:

```
public static ValidationUtility.UnvalidatedCollections GetUnvalidatedCollections(HttpContext context)
{
    return (ValidationUtility.UnvalidatedCollections) context.Items[_unvalidatedCollectionsKey];
}
```

So, are we back in past when we were dependent on `HttpContext.Current`? How to workaround it?

Comment: I have the same issue. +1 for a good question.

Comment: I had the same need so thank you.  One point to mention, just setting the new RouteData() can still throw errors.  To overcome it, I had to add a "controller" and "action" key/value to the routedata before feeding it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can easily be solved by prox-ing ValueProviders that access HttpContext to a the one ignoring it.

I have explained everything in my blog post: [Unit test actions with ValueProviderFactories in ASP.NET MVC3](http://blog.approache.com/2011/03/unit-test-actions-with.html).

The key is this code:

```
public static class ValueProviderFactoresExtensions {
    public static ValueProviderFactoryCollection ReplaceWith<TOriginal>(this ValueProviderFactoryCollection factories, Func<ControllerContext, NameValueCollection> sourceAccessor) {
        var original = factories.FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(TOriginal) == x.GetType());
        if (original != null) {
            var index = factories.IndexOf(original);
            factories[index] = new TestValueProviderFactory(sourceAccessor);
        }
        return factories;
    }

    class TestValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory {
        private readonly Func<ControllerContext, NameValueCollection> sourceAccessor;


        public TestValueProviderFactory(Func<ControllerContext, NameValueCollection> sourceAccessor) {
            this.sourceAccessor = sourceAccessor;
        }


        public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) {
            return new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(sourceAccessor(controllerContext), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
    }        
}
```

So it can be used as:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories
    .ReplaceWith<FormValueProviderFactory>(ctx => ctx.HttpContext.Request.Form)
    .ReplaceWith<QueryStringValueProviderFactory>(ctx => ctx.HttpContext.Request.QueryString);
```

It was actually very easy :)

**UPDATE**: As mentioned in comments you should remember to:

1. set `ctx.HttpContext.Request.ContentType` property to some not-null value, otherwise the JsonValueProviderFactory will throw exception. I prefer create a mock and set default value there.
2. replace the `HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory` as it can be used during binding.
3. watch out for other dependencies you might have in the project.

Comment: Good work! Note: you have to set ctx.HttpContext.Request.ContentType property to some not-null value, otherwise the JsonValueProviderFactory will throw exception.

Comment: I also had to replace the `HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory` to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling ValueProviderFactories.Factories, ModelBinders.Binders, or any other static accessor from within a unit test.  That's precisely why ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider exists - so that you can provide a mocked IValueProvider of your own creation rather than relying on the static defaults (which assume the MVC pipeline is running).

Comment: Mocking `IValueProvider` is a ridiculous amount of work. It will require reimplementing dozens of the ASP.NET MVC features. It is not even funny how it used to be testable, and now it is NOT.