# Moq-ing a 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit, moq, http-status-code-404

I have the following 404 error ActionResult which is thrown when web pages are not found:

```
public ActionResult InvokeHttp404(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
      IController errorController = new ErrorController();
      var errorRoute = new RouteData();
      errorRoute.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
      errorRoute.Values.Add("action", "Http404");
      errorRoute.Values.Add("url", httpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString);
      errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(httpContext, errorRoute));
      return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

And I am attempting to unit test it with the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Details_Get_404Handler()
        {
            // Arrange
            var controller = GetController(new Repository(), FakeHttpContext());

            // Act
            var result = controller.Details(3442399) as ViewResult; // invalid Id (not found)

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("NotFound", result.ViewName);
        }
```

I have been stuck on this test for a long time now, it would throw a null exception on the line of code that requests the `Url.OriginalString`. After reading around I found this previous post [Mocking HttpContextBase with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228179/mocking-httpcontextbase-with-moq) and found the second answer very helpful, as follows: (I added a line that took care of the Url string)

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
        {
            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
            var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
            var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();

            request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
            request.Setup(req => req.ApplicationPath).Returns("~/");
            request.Setup(req => req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/");
            request.Setup(req => req.PathInfo).Returns(string.Empty);
            response.Setup(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns((string virtualPath) => virtualPath);
            user.Setup(usr => usr.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
            identity.SetupGet(ident => ident.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);

            return context.Object;
        }
```

So I have finally beaten the line of code requesting the Url.OriginalString thanks to that post and answer. But I am now stuck on line of code straight after it:
`errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(httpContext, errorRoute));`. The test now fails with a null reference error on that line. I am slightly confused as to what is null here as I have already faked the httpContext. Could anyone help me with this?

Edit:

Altered ValueProviderFactoriesExtensions:

```
public static class ValueProviderFactoresExtensions
{
    public static ValueProviderFactoryCollection ReplaceNameValueCollectionWith<TOriginal>(this ValueProviderFactoryCollection factories, Func<ControllerContext, NameValueCollection> sourceAccessor)
    {
        var original = factories.FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(TOriginal) == x.GetType());
        if (original != null)
        {
            var index = factories.IndexOf(original);
            factories[index] = new NameValueCollectionProviderFactory(sourceAccessor);
        }
        return factories;
    }

    public static ValueProviderFactoryCollection ReplaceHttpFileCollectionWith<TOriginal>(this ValueProviderFactoryCollection factories, Func<ControllerContext, HttpFileCollectionBase> sourceAccessor)
    {
        var original = factories.FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(TOriginal) == x.GetType());
        if (original != null)
        {
            var index = factories.IndexOf(original);
            factories[index] = new HttpFileCollectionProviderFactory(sourceAccessor);
        }
        return factories;
    }

    class NameValueCollectionProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
    {
        private readonly Func<ControllerContext, NameValueCollection> sourceAccessor;


        public NameValueCollectionProviderFactory(Func<ControllerContext, NameValueCollection> sourceAccessor)
        {
            this.sourceAccessor = sourceAccessor;
        }


        public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            return new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(sourceAccessor(controllerContext), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

    }
    class HttpFileCollectionProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
    {
        private readonly Func<ControllerContext, HttpFileCollectionBase> sourceAccessor;


        public HttpFileCollectionProviderFactory(Func<ControllerContext, HttpFileCollectionBase> sourceAccessor)
        {
            this.sourceAccessor = sourceAccessor;
        }


        public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            return new HttpFileCollectionValueProvider(controllerContext);
        }

    }
}
```

Code altered in response to Marnix's answer:

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
        {
            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
            var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
            var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
            var files = new Mock<HttpFileCollectionBase>();



            request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
            request.Setup(req => req.ApplicationPath).Returns("~/");
            request.Setup(req => req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/");
            request.Setup(req => req.PathInfo).Returns(string.Empty);
            request.Setup(req => req.ContentType).Returns("text/html");
            request.Setup(req => req.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
            request.Setup(req => req.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
            request.Setup(req => req.Files).Returns(files.Object);
            response.Setup(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns((string virtualPath) => virtualPath);
            user.Setup(usr => usr.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
            identity.SetupGet(ident => ident.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
            context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);

            ValueProviderFactories.Factories
                .ReplaceNameValueCollectionWith<FormValueProviderFactory>(ctx => ctx.HttpContext.Request.Form)
                .ReplaceNameValueCollectionWith<QueryStringValueProviderFactory>(ctx => ctx.HttpContext.Request.QueryString)
                .ReplaceHttpFileCollectionWith<HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory>(ctx => ctx.HttpContext.Request.Files);

            return context.Object;
        }
```

Still can't get it to work, still throws a null reference on the same line of code. Don't know if stack trace is struggling to find view? stack trace:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5229581/293712

Comment: I have an error controller like the guy in that question but what I am asking is how to unit test a 404 error controller using Moq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking up the context for a controller is a bit tricky. In MVC3 there's an additional step to prevent the value providers from touching HttpContext.Current.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346871/64096) explains what you need to do.

**Update:** You probably don use the ValueProviderFactories directly, however the ActionInvoker on the controller does. Somewhere deep down the default implementation for the value providers accesses HttpContext.Current which is not set outside of a web request, causing a NullReferenceException during unit tests. You can prevent this by replacing the default value providers (as described in the linked answer).

Copy the `ValueProviderFactoresExtensions` class from the link above into your test project add the following code to your `FakeHttpContext` method:

```
var form = new NameValueCollection();
var queryString = new NameValueCollection();

request.Setup( x => x.Form ).Returns( form );
request.Setup( x => x.QueryString ).Returns( queryString );

ValueProviderFactories.Factories
.ReplaceWith<FormValueProviderFactory>(ctx => form)
.ReplaceWith<QueryStringValueProviderFactory>(ctx => queryString);
```

Comment: Have not used ValueProviderFactories before, could show how I might call them from my test method considering I have the ValueProviderFactoresExtensions class in the question you point to? Would still like to to see a solution in Moq if anyone has one...

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how and why you need to tweak the ValueProviderFactories.

Comment: stack trace in the test result details is now getting past the namevaluecollections but now seems to be stuck finding the viewname... ? I have posted the updated code that I am using in my question - its not exactly as you said but same difference, right?

Comment: That looks about right. My best guess is that your Error controller is trying to return a View result. When you call `Execute` the full pipeline is executed, including the view. Since you're in a unit test, the ViewEngine most likely won't be able to find the view. You have two options; stub the view engine or reconsider the way you implemented your controller. For example, you could throw a HttpException with error code 404 and handle that with a custom HandleErrorAttribute implementation. That would make your controller a lot easier to test.